# ¿Peticion ajax no detecta variables de PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Estoy teniendo problemas al hacer una petición ajax donde hago la llamada  a un archivo php llamado closeuser.php. El archivo closeuser.php contiene una condición, donde traigo el id de la sesion iniciada, así como un campo llamado id_sesion de la BD de datos.

La condición es que si el id de sesion del usuario de la BD, es el mismo que el ultimo  id de sesion logeado, si es el mismo lo deja navegar, si no es el mismo, manda un string 'success', después en la respuesta dentro del AJAX comparo si no es el mismo string cierra sesion, si es el mismo lo deja navegar.

El problema es que el local si me funciona, pero al subirlo al servidor no funciona, me manda un string vacio, y al parecer no las variables de id de sesión no me muestra nada.  Dejo mi codigo para que sea mas entendible.

Codigo ajax:

```
$(function() { 
    cron(); // Lanzo cron la primera vez
    function cron() {
         $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "closeuser.php", 
          data: { action: 1 }
          })
        .done(function(msg) {
            var trimmedString = msg.trim();
            console.log(trimmedString)
          if( trimmedString == 'success' ) {  // Valida si el server devolvió 'success'
                 location.href='logoutuser.php';
          }
        });
    }
    setInterval(function() {
        cron();
    }, 10000); // cada 10 segundos
});
```

Codigo closeuser.php

```
<?php

require_once 'Connections/sesionunica.php';
$connection_s = new sesionunica();

 if(!isset($_SESSION["id_user"])){ 
        echo"<script>location.href='index.php';</script>";  
    } 

if(isset($_POST["action"])) { // Se pasa una acción
    switch(sprintf("%d", $_POST["action"])) { // ¿Qué acción?
        case 1:
            cerrar();
            break;
        default:
        echo "default";
    }
}
function cerrar(){
    $ses = session_id();
    $connection_s = new sesionunica();
    $userById = $connection_s->getUsers($_SESSION["id_user"]);
    if ($userById["id_sesion"] <> $ses) {
    echo "success"; 
    }
}

?>
```

Codigo de de Connections/sesionunica.php:

```
<?php
require_once("conexion.php");
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
        session_start(); 
    } 
class sesionunica extends Connection{

 return $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NAMED);
    }
     public function getUsers($id_user)
    {   
        $conexion = new Connection();
        $pdo = $conexion->getConexion();
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id_user = :id_user ");
        $statement->bindValue('id_user', $id_user);
        $statement->execute();
        return $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NAMED);
    }
   
 
}
```

Si imprimo desde un archivo por ejemplo index.php lo que hay en closeuser.php entonces si me muestra lo que contiene las variables. Alguna idea en que esta pasando? se los agradezco por adelantado.

Comment: ¿Revisaste el log de errores en el servidor? Por otra parte la pregunta está planteada de forma muy confusa, la leí tres veces y no logro entender con claridad el problema.